# Firefox does not display inputs on Azure website

Tags: html, firefox, input

hello i have a web app that works fine on chrome but on firefox it does not display my checkbox, inputs, text area etc...

Even if I have a page that only have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">   <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="MSTHEMECOMPATIBLE" content="no">
<title>Checkbox Test</title>   </head>   <body>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="radio">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
<input type="button">
<input type="file">   </body> </html>
```

does not show! BUT with the same browser i went to a website hosted elsewhere and this very same code works, when i run it locally it works... please help me!

Again with the same code, When using chrome it works.

im hosted on Azure .... does it makes a difference?

why would my hosted page don't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes and radio buttons are not displayed on Firefox when 
`<meta http-equiv="MSTHEMECOMPATIBLE" content="no">` is specified.

Comment: Hello thank you for this answer, i actually tried with and without, in both scenario, it does show locally but not on azure on firefox, but does work on chrome in both location. I did a ton of research for some fixes online before posting, i should not have written that line you are right.